# Extract record from dictionary list where key and value does not contains given value list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dictionary

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> firstList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();   
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("name", "abc");
dict.Add("age", "22");
dict.Add("address", "xyz,aa");
dict.Add("contact", "111");
firstList .Add(dict);
Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict2 .Add("name", "pqr");
dict2 .Add("age", "25");
dict2 .Add("address", "xxx,bb");
dict2 .Add("contact", "4222");
firstList .Add(dict2);
Dictionary<string, string> dict3 = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict3 .Add("name", "aa");
dict3 .Add("age", "24");
dict3 .Add("address", "xxx,aa");
dict3 .Add("contact", "aaa");
firstList .Add(dict3);
```

return record where list doesn't not contains key = 'address' and name= 'aa'

Update :- return record where name= 'aa'

Comment: Why do you have (lot's of) dictionaries with the same keys instead of a dedicated class with (correctly typed) properties `Name`, `Age` (`int`), `Address` and `Contact`? If you _need_ to access it via a `string` key, you can always implement an [Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/). But a dedicated class usually causes much less headache than a bunch of "stringly typed" dictionaries. -- Then it would become `list.Where(item => item.Address is null && item.Name == "aa");`

Comment: @Dale
i am using dynamic list so i cant specify dedicated class with properties and i don't know how to create generic dedicated class which properties are dynamic, so i am using dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple with linq:

```
var result = firstList.Where(x => !(x.ContainsKey("address") 
                                && x.ContainsKey(name)
                                && x["name"] == "aa")).ToList();
```

and if only one record is required back then use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var result = firstList.Where(x => !(x.ContainsKey("address") 
                                && x.ContainsKey(name)
                                && x["name"] == "aa")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Don't forget to add on top:

```
using System.Linq;
```

### UDPATE:

```
var result = firstList.Where(x => 
                                && x.ContainsKey(name)
                                && x["name"] != "aa")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: actually i need those record which key is 'name' and value is not equal to 'aa'

Comment: @shahbazusmani you will need to update your condition accordingly, see updated answer

Comment: thank you your updated answer worked for me, one more thing i want to ask you if  i want to extract list where name doesn't contains 'a'

Comment: change condition to : `!x["name"].Contains("a")`